# BroadcastOn not firing in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

So, I am trying to make use of the broadcasting functionality in laravel to broadcast notifications on certain events.

```
<?php

namespace Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ImportSuccess implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $job_id;
    public $patent_id;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($job_id, $patent_id)
    {
        $this->job_id = $job_id;
        $this->patent_id = $patent_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        dd(5);
        return [];
    }
}
```

I have tried dying and dumping even tried logging using the Log facade but  the broadcastOn method is not firing. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? I am coming from an old version of laravel and updated it recently so I installed the BroadcastServiceProvider manually and registered it in the app.php too. So what am I missing?

I can use Pusher class to fire using the Pusher class but not via broadcasting.

Comment: Just asking. Do you have any failed queue jobs? Is the event registered and fired?

Comment: Event fires successfully. I have made sure of it. The queue jobs run fine too.

Comment: Is the BROADCAST_DRIVER (pusher) defined in your .env and configured in config/broadcasting.php? You would probably get an error in your logs if not, but I thought it is good to check as well.